# JavaMail Spring boot properties does not recognize properties

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, properties-file

I have a spring boot application with javamail, i configure spring.properties but it seems to not take properties to send email.

```
#mail properties
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username = eeee@gmail.com 
spring.mail.password = eeee
spring.mail.protocol = smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false
spring.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

here the java code to send email

```
@Service
public class MailSenderServiceImpl implements IMailSenderService{

@Autowired
JavaMailSender mailSender;


@Override
public void sendEmailStatusNotification(Shipment shipment) throws IOException, MessagingException{
    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
    message.setFrom(shipment.getSender().getSenderEmail());
    message.setTo(new String[] {shipment.getRecipient().getRecipientEmail()});
    message.setSubject("Shipment "+shipment.getTrackingNumber()+"status update");
    message.setText("the shipment status is now :"+shipment.getStatus().getLabel());
    this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

here we see this error

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

By default `spring.properties` is not a properties source, try putting them in `application.properties`.

Comment: spring properties are added in a file called application.properties